# Query plan for a query with limit clause

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, explain

I used the `EXPLAIN` command in a PostgreSQL (version 11.12) DB to see the query plan of the query `select col1, col2 from some_table limit 10` and I got the following: -

```
some_db=> EXPLAIN select col1, col2 from some_table limit 10;
                                QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.32 rows=10 width=33)
   ->  Seq Scan on user_dim  (cost=0.00..263325.95 rows=8106495 width=33)
(2 rows)
```

As per my understanding, the lower the step in a query plan, the earlier it is executed. But I noticed that this query plan first sequentially scans the entire table and then selects the first two rows. I was surprised to see this as I had expected that the limit clause would not let the full sequential scan happen.

I tried finding an answer to this in [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-CAVEATS) and found this:

"There are cases in which the actual and estimated values won't match up well, but nothing is really wrong. One such case occurs when plan node execution is stopped short by a LIMIT or similar effect. For example, in the LIMIT query we used before,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tenk1 WHERE unique1 < 100 AND unique2 > 9000 LIMIT 2;

                                                          QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.29..14.71 rows=2 width=244) (actual time=0.177..0.249 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using tenk1_unique2 on tenk1  (cost=0.29..72.42 rows=10 width=244) (actual time=0.174..0.244 rows=2 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (unique2 > 9000)
         Filter: (unique1 < 100)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 287
 Planning time: 0.096 ms
 Execution time: 0.336 ms
```

the estimated cost and row count for the Index Scan node are shown as though it were run to completion. But in reality, the Limit node stopped requesting rows after it got two, so the actual row count is only 2 and the run time is less than the cost estimate would suggest. This is not an estimation error, only a discrepancy in the way the estimates and true values are displayed."

What I understand from this is that this is just a display issue and this query plan won't be executed actually (i.e. only the number of rows specified in the limit clause would be fetched). Is my understanding correct or am I missing something here?

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Your question is a bit of a curve ball.  Let me ask: Why are you wanting to do a `LIMIT` query without an `ORDER BY` clause?  Generally, doing this makes no sense.  If you _had_ included an `ORDER BY` clause, then the explain plan would probably also include some kind of sort operation.

Comment: Actually, I stumbled across this while preparing a document for best practices for SQL optimization in which one of the points was to use `EXPLAIN` to estimate the cost of the query. And hence I used this select query with a limit clause as an example. My aim was to just demonstrate various parts of a query plan. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For the sequential scan, cost is 0.00..263325.95.

0.00 is the startup cost. This is the time expended before the output phase can begin.

263325.95 is the estimated total cost. This is stated on the assumption that the plan node is run to completion, i.e., all available rows are retrieved. In practice a node's parent node might stop short of reading all available rows.

For this node, rows=8106495. This is the estimated number of rows output by this plan node. Again, the node is assumed to be run to completion.

In plain english, the sequential scan will start outputing results to the parent node right away (startup cost is 0.00), and would output 8106495 rows for a total cost of 263325.95 if not stopped.

But of course it will be stopped before, because of the parent node!

Parent node (the limit): cost=0.00..0.32 rows=10
This node will also start outputing results immediately (startup cost is 0.00) and if not stopped will output 10 rows for a total cost of 0.32.

[source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)